# SQL Update query with Inner join gives Lock wait timeout exceeded

Tags: mysql, sql, timeout, inner-join

I have following query which is running on two tables having more than 80,000 and 40,000 records each:

```
update 
profileimageurls piu 
inner join 
profileuniqref pr
on piu.imageurl = pr.uniqueimageurl
set piu.uniqueimagekey = pr.keyid;
```

Table structure of profileimageurls:

```
 Field              Type                  Null
 KeyID              bigint(20) unsigned   NO
 UserID             bigint(20) unsigned   NO
 ImageURL           varchar(4000)         NO
 UniqueImageURL     varchar(4000)         YES
 Error              varchar(10000)        YES
 Status             tinyint(3) unsigned   YES
 uniqueImageKeyid   bigint(20) unsigned   YES
```

Tables Structure of profileuniqref:

```
 Field          Type
 KeyId          bigint(20) unsigned
 uniqueimageurl varchar(4000)
 md5hash        varchar(32)
 md5hashbinary  varchar(16)
```

When I am running this query, I am getting Lock and Wait timeout repeatedly.

Comment: Do you have indexes on the `imageurl` columns?

Comment: Adding indexes on URL columns in both tables.

Comment: Make your query faster (no more than 50 seconds), or increase innodb_lock_wait_timeout from default 50 seconds to much more --> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have indexes on the columns used in the join condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you have foreign keys between joined tables and you are updating keys, this could cause mysql to update key data between these two tables.

Comment: FYI: I am referring uniqueImageKeyId from profileuniqre table. But I have not added an FK constraint between tow tables. What is meant by `this could cause mysql to update key data between these two tables.`, and how does it impact the  query.